# Составление массива

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день!

Есть база `main` в ней записаны записи и соответствующие им даты.
нужно составить массив с количеством записей по месяцам.

```
Array (
 [0] => January-2014/10,
 [1] => December-2013/12,
 [2] => November-2013/1,
)
```

Я составил массив с датами по месяцам

```
function all_date() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `date` FROM `main` ".$AUTH." ORDER BY `date` DESC");
    $year_old = "0";
    for(;$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);) {
       $year_row = $row['date'];
       $year = date('F-Y',$year_row);
       if($year != $year_old){
          $year_old = $year;
          $_darr[] = $year;
       }
    }
    return $_darr;
}
```

Результатом выполнения вышеописанного кода:

```
Array
(
    [0] => January-2014
    [1] => December-2013
    [2] => November-2013
)
```

Теперь нужно к соответствующему месяцу добавить количество записей. Не могу сообразить как лучше дописать их. Если есть какие-нибудь идеи, прошу помочь.

P.S. **January-2014** подобное написание нужно для дальнейшего составления **`BETWEEN`** в `sql` запросе.

P.P.S. Не знаю как правильно написать заголовок вопроса :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вашу проблему легко решить использованием `group by` в запросе:

```
SELECT date_format(date, "%M-%Y") AS MONTH, count(1) AS qty
    FROM main 
    GROUP BY date_format(date, "%M-%Y")
    ORDER BY date DESC;
```

В итоге вы получите готовый результат из двух колонок - месяц и количество записей в месяце: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6be27/2